# How to add Page numbers to a fixed title cell (without headers/footers)?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I was trying to consolidate some of my route cards which was earlier made in word to excel. The company is very strict with regard to formatting.[This is how it was earlier, and has to maintain it like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMOwO.png) The problem with this is that I can't seem to get the page numbers to work. If I put a header/footer, the page numbers will be outside of the box/borders and that would be a problem. I even tried using the VBA code which was available in one if the websites as follows:

```
Sub pagenumber()
'updateby Extendoffice 20160506
    Dim xVPC As Integer
    Dim xHPC As Integer
    Dim xVPB As VPageBreak
    Dim xHPB As HPageBreak
    Dim xNumPage As Integer
    xHPC = 1
    xVPC = 1
    If ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Order = xlDownThenOver Then
        xHPC = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1
    Else
        xVPC = ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count + 1
    End If
    xNumPage = 1
    For Each xVPB In ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks
        If xVPB.Location.Column > ActiveCell.Column Then Exit For
        xNumPage = xNumPage + xHPC
    Next
    For Each xHPB In ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
        If xHPB.Location.Row > ActiveCell.Row Then Exit For
        xNumPage = xNumPage + xVPC
    Next
    ActiveCell = "Page " & xNumPage & " of " & Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
End Sub
```

But the problem with this is that the page number will remain the same throughout the document as it is part of the title which thr rows remains fixed and not changing. Is there an alternative to do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have I would propose to use a function in the individual cell:

`=pagenumber2text()`

Result for 9 pages (page break view):
[image]

The following code will output your "page x of y":

```
Function pagenumber2text()
'updateby Extendoffice 20160506
    Dim xVPC As Integer
    Dim xHPC As Integer
    Dim xVPB As VPageBreak
    Dim xHPB As HPageBreak
    Dim xNumPage As Integer
    xHPC = 1
    xVPC = 1
    If ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Order = xlDownThenOver Then
        xHPC = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1
    Else
        xVPC = ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count + 1
    End If
    xNumPage = 1
    For Each xVPB In ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks
        If xVPB.Location.Column > Application.ThisCell.Column Then Exit For
        xNumPage = xNumPage + xHPC
    Next
    For Each xHPB In ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
        If xHPB.Location.Row > Application.ThisCell.Row Then Exit For
        xNumPage = xNumPage + xVPC
    Next
'    pagenumber2text = "Page " & xNumPage & " of " & Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
    pagenumber2text = "Page " & xNumPage & " of " & HowManyPagesBreaks
End Function


'source https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/printed-pages.htm
Function HowManyPagesBreaks()

    Dim iHpBreaks As Integer, iVBreaks As Integer
    Dim iTotPages As Integer

    iHpBreaks = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1
    iVBreaks = ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count + 1
    iTotPages = iHpBreaks * iVBreaks

'    MsgBox "This sheet will require " & iTotPages & _
'    " page(s) to print", vbInformation, "OzGrid.com"
    HowManyPagesBreaks = iTotPages
End Function
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the swift reply.

the problem with this is that the 'Page number' cell is a part of the title rows, which will remain as it is without any change. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I see two alternatives: (1) get rid of the title rows an repeat the page header on every page. (2) get rid of the title rows and use excel headers and arrange everything (zoom and size) to keep page numbers inside box/borders! Good luck!